# “$P$ is true” is true

Tags: logic, proof-writing, formal-languages

Here is an example of a proof by induction that my teacher gave:

> Let's prove by induction over $n\in\mathbb N$ the property $P(n):$«$n+3>2$».
>
> - $P(0)$ is clear
> - $\forall n\in\mathbb N$, $(n+3)+1>n+3>2$ so $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$
>
> Thus $\forall n\in\mathbb N$, $P(n)$ is true.

I was wondering why we need to specify “is true” in the conclusion rather than just writing $P(n)$. It seems to me that any argument to that effect would force us to write “$P(n)$ is true” is true; “‘$P(n)$ is true’ is true” is true and so on.

Comment: Just to be clear, that proof is false, $0+1$ is not $>2$.

Comment: I'm sure you know that's not the point.

Comment: I think the question is just a matter of semantics.  Some people refer to $P(n)$ as the statement, without regard to its truth.  Thus I could have the statement "$n$ is a prime number".  In that case, I would be comfortable saying that $P(5)$ is true but $P(6)$ is false.  I don't know what conventions your professor has assumed.

Comment: Is there a commonly accepted convention?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  And, of course,  it is often a good idea to add detail to dispel potential ambiguities.

Answer (score 1):

The inductive argument shows that $\forall n \ P(n)$. No need to paste "is true" after that ...

However, you *could* choose to add the "is true" for reading sake; there is nothing against that. And, just because you choose to do so does not force you to get the infinite regress as indicated.